# Finding a difference in looked-up cells

Tags: excel

Suppose I have two datasets, consisting of rankings and IDs. What I'm trying now is to find same IDs and calculate the difference in ranking. This is what I typed up:

```
INDEX($I$2:$I$60,MATCH(R2,$J$2:$J$60)) - INDEX($M$2:$M$60, MATCH(R2,$N$2:$N$60))
```

Column I holding the rankings of the first table and column J the corresponding ID, same for the second table with M and N, and the R column holds all of those IDs once more, and in the S column I want to use this function to display the rating difference.

Again for clarity (well... I try): The ratings are in column I and M, and I'm finding them for the ID in R2 by looking up that ID in J and N.

From the looks of it, the result is not even remotely what I intend to get, and I can't find a pattern in it.

Comment: I notice that you're not using a parameter of 0 (or FALSE) for the MATCH functions, which would mean that, in order to guarantee correct results, the entries in the ranges J2:J60 and N2:N60 would have to be sorted in strictly ascending order. I presume that this is the case?

Comment: @XORLX Nope, that wasn't the case. Darn, that's irritating default behaviour. Well thanks, that was all I needed. Stupid question, really, sorry. :/

Comment: Not at all. And I take your point - based on the number of occasions on which I perform exact matches vs non-exact, I also would prefer to see the default parameter as zero.

Comment: Edit: technically I suppose I should say "linear vs binary", rather than "exact vs non-exact".